# I want to edit a Config.XML file using Ansible on Lines 26, 31, 32, 37 with myinstanceURL, myinstanceID, myPasscode, myID

Tags: regex, ansible, ansible-2.x

[config.xml file snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHqW8.png)

i tried with this to edit line 26 but it fails -

```
ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
  path: /etc/selinux/config
  regexp: '[<]+[a-z]+[ ]+[a-z]+[=]+["]+[a-z]+["]+[ ]+[a-z]+[=]+["]+[a-z]+[:]+[\/]+[\/]+[A-Z_]+[.]+[a-z\-]+[.]+[a-z]{2,3}+[\/]+["]+[\/]+[>]'
  line: "google.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use these for the RegEx:

YOUR_INSTANCE_PASSWORD_HERE
YOUR_INSTANCE_USER_NAME_HERE
YOUR_MIDSERVER_NAME_GOES_HERE
YOUR_INSTANCE (This one last, or at least after YOUR_INSTANCE_PASSWORD_HERE, or it will replace two lines and not do what you want)

So
regexp: 'YOUR_MIDSERVER_NAME_GOES_HERE'
line: 'google.com'

Comment: No., it does not replace the google.com. it wrote somewhere in the xml body.

Comment: Hi., Yes that works.,

    - name: Edit Instance URL on config.xml
      become: true
      replace:
        path: /foo1/foo2/foo3.xml
        regexp: "YOUR_INSTANCE.foo-foo.com"
        replace: "ReplaceThisFoo"